# Unistall apache 2.4 + php 7.1

Tags: php, macos, apache2

Ребят, нужна помощь, скажите какими командами или как вообще возможно перманентно удалить Apache 2.4  и PHP 7.1 с MAC OS High Sierra?

Comment: А вы их как ставили?

Comment: @Axenow через терминал, пакетным менеджером Brew(HomeBrew)

Comment: Ну тогда также через brew uninstall и т.д. и т.п.
Потом удалите папки, где были ваши файлы и всё.

Comment: @Axenow я по этому и пишу сюда, потому что я не знаю конкретных команд для удаления

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

- Получить весь лист всех установленных пакетов через brew

  ```
  brew list
  ```
- Либо если знаете название пакета, то:

  ```
  brew list mtr
  ```
- Удалить пакет:

  ```
  brew uninstall mtr
  Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.92... (12 files, 181.9KB)
  ```

Для вас это должны быть команды:

```
brew uninstall apache2
brew uninstall php@7.0
brew uninstall php@7.1
```